# Doctrine's equals, doesn't return expected result,

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine

This is my structure.

```
{
  "title" : "wastelands",
  "playerLimit" : [ 
    1, 
    2, 
    4 ],
  "mode" : "coop" 
}
```

Now i want to select where playerLimit contains a arbitrary value, with mongodb i can do like this.

```
> db.Map.find({playerLimit : 4})
{ "title" : "wastelands", "playerLimit" : [ 1, 2, 4 ], "mode" : "coop" }
```

Which i suppose would correspond to this in doctrine

```
$q = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')
->getRepository('AcmeGameBundle:Map')
>createQueryBuilder();
$q->field('playerLimit')->equals($playerLimit);
```

$playerLimit being 4, all i get when executed is, null.

How is this done? the Docs doesn't seems to explain clearly enough.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, that

```
$q->field('playerLimit')->equals($playerLimit);
```

infact does work like expected, but the paramFetcher in Symfony was fetching the integer as a String.

The solution therefore was

```
$q->field('playerLimit')->equals( (int) $playerLimit);
```